# Gson does not map values in Java

Tags: java, kotlin, gson

I get this result from an API:

```
{"sessionID":"","randomKey":"","id":0,"userName":"","useIPAddress":"","usePortNo":"","response":{"code":-24,"message":"Incorrect credential","postedDateTime":null,"accountNo":0,"trxnNo":0,"changeTypeID":0}}
```

and my class is this:

```
class ResponseLoginParam {
    val RandomKey: String? = null
    val SessionID: String? = null
    val UseIPAddress: String? = null
    val UsePortNo: Int? = null
    val UserName: String? = null
    val Response: Response? = Response()
}

class Response {
    val Code: Int? = null
    val Message: String? = null
    val PostedDateTime: String? = null
    val AccountNo: Int? = null
    val ChangeTypeID: Int? = null
}
```

for some reason it does not map to my object. But if I get the result like this:

```
{"SessionID":"","RandomKey":"","Id":0,"UserName":"","UseIPAddress":"","UsePortNo":"","Response":{"Code":-24,"Message":"Incorrect credential","PostedDateTime":null,"AccountNo":0,"TrxnNo":0,"ChangeTypeID":0}}
```

It is now capitalized, I can map the values properly. Why is this?

Comment: When you create your Gson object with the GsonBuilder, set the FieldNaming policy as `gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)`.

Comment: Can you please add your code specific to getting the API response and mapping to your class with Gson?

Comment: Hi Ibanez1408. I have edited a number of your questions, in order to improve their succinctness and readability. They tend to reflect quite a pleading, obsequious tone, which readers may find coercive - do remember they are volunteers. Could I ask you to stick to technical writing? You are writing not just to solve your immediate problem, but to help create a Q&A for many future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either name class and json fields equally, or define serialization name:

```
  class Response {
    @SerializedName("code") // since its "code" in json
    val Code: Int? = null
    //no need for annotation because class field name equals json field name
    val message: String? = null
   }
```